# Are there security risks with using someone else's ISP?

Tags: network, isp

I recently found out that, due to a mix-up at Australia's National Broadband Network, the connection to our Internet Service Provider had been swapped with a neighbour's. It doesn't look like the neighbours used our ISP, but we unknowingly used their ISP for a couple of months until the situation was discovered and rectified.

Are there potential security risks from what's happened?

For example, I'm aware that it would be risky to connect to a neighbour's WiFi - but is it equally bad to have just used their ISP (even though we never shared a LAN)?